# Modal is unresponsive and locks everything on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make a modal for the logging the user in. However, when my modal pops up, everything (including the modal itself is getting faded or greyed out). I'm unable to click on anything be it the background or the buttons on the modal. Usually, I should be able to dismiss the modal by clicking elsewhere or on the close button of the modal. But now, I'm unable to close it by any means. I have to reload the page to close the modal.

Two scripts which I had to load to get the modal working at all:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here's my modal code:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" style="z-index:99999999;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the link that calls the modal:

```
<div id="fh5co-page">
<header id="fh5co-header" role="banner" style="Border-bottom:solid;position:fixed;border-width:1px;background-color:rgba(127,127,127,0.85);">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-inner">
            <a href="#"><img alt="XYZ" class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'assets/images/XYZimage.png' %}" style="float:left;height:70px;width:180px;"></a>
<nav role="navigation" style="float:right;margin-top:4%;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="about.html">View Packages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">Try a test!</a></li>
                    <li class="cta"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

What needs to change here? Please help! Thanks!

Screenshot:[image]

CSS code for class cta, header-inner, fh5co-header, and fh5co-page:

```
#fh5co-header nav ul li.cta {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li.cta a {
  padding-left: 16px !important;
  padding-right: 16px !important;
  padding-top: 7px !important;
  padding-bottom: 7px !important;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li.cta a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #00B906;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li.cta a:hover:after {
  display: none;
}
#fh5co-offcanvas ul li.cta {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#fh5co-offcanvas ul li.cta a {
  padding-left: 16px !important;
  padding-right: 16px !important;
  padding-top: 7px !important;
  padding-bottom: 7px !important;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#fh5co-offcanvas ul li.cta a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#fh5co-offcanvas ul li.cta a:hover:after {
  display: none;
}


#fh5co-page {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
}

#fh5co-offcanvas, .fh5co-nav-toggle, #fh5co-page {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#fh5co-offcanvas, .fh5co-nav-toggle, #fh5co-page {
  position: relative;
}

#fh5co-page {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.offcanvas-visible #fh5co-page {
  -moz-transform: translateX(-275px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-275px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-275px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-275px);
  transform: translateX(-275px);
}



#fh5co-header {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #fh5co-header {
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
  }
}
#fh5co-header .header-inner {
  height: 70px;
  /* padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px; */
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -ms-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
#fh5co-header h1 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#fh5co-header h1 a {
  color: white;
}
#fh5co-header h1 a > span {
  color: #00B906;
}
#fh5co-header h1 a:hover, #fh5co-header h1 a:active, #fh5co-header h1 a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
#fh5co-header h1, #fh5co-header nav {
  /* margin: 38px 0 0 0; */
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#fh5co-header nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #fh5co-header nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
#fh5co-header nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 -0px 0 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li a i {
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 7px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  -o-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li a:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li a:active, #fh5co-header nav ul li a:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li.cta {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li.cta a {
  padding-left: 16px !important;
  padding-right: 16px !important;
  padding-top: 7px !important;
  padding-bottom: 7px !important;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li.cta a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #00B906;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li.cta a:hover:after {
  display: none;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li.active a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#fh5co-header nav ul li.active a:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Screenshot of Modal with Z-index higher than page header element:
[image]

Screenshot of Modal with Z-index lower than page header:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here the updated code for the bootstrap modal function.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline with-arrow"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="ppu-start">Get started <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

you are not added data-toggle and data-taget attribute. if you add this, close button working fine.

Comment: Bala, thanks for responding but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I updated the code above to reflect the data-toggle and data-target, but I am running into the same problem. Let me know if you need additional code to diagnose this (if so, which). Any other ideas?

Comment: can you provide me your css code. and show me what type of problem you are facing. just take a screen shot and send it.

Comment: Hi, I've added the screenshot and CSS code. Have a look and let me know what you are able to make of it. Thanks!

Comment: here in my system it is working proper. the modal window showing separate and not grey out of the modal. may be your body tag code need to add something.  did you add any z-index value for the page or modal? coz it will affect only that reason.

Comment: I played around with Z-index. That is also not the issue - with lower z-index, the modal goes below page elements, and with higher z-index the modal appears, above. In both cases, the Modal and the page is greyed out and locked. See screenshot. I applied z-index on modal parent div, modal-dialog div, and modal-content div as well as with no z-index anywhere on the modal. All of the cases, had the same issue- everything is locked.

Bala, as and when you think about this, please tag or share with anyone you know who could help solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Place modal after your html code ends. Then place the code bellow on your css.

```
.modal-backdrop {
/* bug fix - no overlay */    
display: none;}
```